# API in combination with a CMS: how to store HTML?

Tags: angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api, azure-table-storage

As a learning process I'm trying to create a CMS system. 
At the moment I have the following setup:

```
- - - API - - -
- - / - - \ - -
- MVC - - Angular
```

The API is communicating with the database and is used by Angular to update/insert resources. 
The idea is that ALL clients (for now MVC and Angular, in the future mobile) need to use the API to have a single entry point (avoiding duplicates).

This is working perfectly fine, but, Angular is used to create for instance pages for my CMS. These pages contain HTML. 
It's easy to read and display the HTML for my MVC application, but what for mobile applications?

How do other CMS systems/websites handle this issue? Do they parse the HTML on the client (i.e. a mobile client) and display it properly?

My Page resource (model) looks like this:

```
public class PageModel
{
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Html { get; set; }
        public DateTime PostedOn { get; set; }
        public string SidebarId { get; set; }
}
```

I was thinking of storing an array of Paragraphs instead of plain Html. This could work fine, I could loop over all the paragraphs and display them instead of dumping the HTML. But then, what for span/strong/em/... tags (and more important, how to store this? I'm using table storage)?

Comment: What do you mean by mobile - Apps or mobile websites?

What type of content is in the HTML?

Comment: An APP. You can compare the CMS with Wordpress. The type of content can be anything. div's/images/strong/input/...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data should be separated from any presentation logic. Maybe consider storing large text as something like MarkDown, then parse mark down to HTML for your Web sites, and into an appropriate format for a standalone app.

Comment: I was thinking the same, a colleague suggested me to use a WebViewControl for my mobile app and keep the HTML as is. But still this doesn't solve the major problem. I think I'll go for something like MD.